# Link to external site on button Click Preact

Tags: preact

I'm trying to send users to an external website on a button click like this:

```
      <button onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
       Link to=`${posts.ctaURL1}`
      }}>{posts.ctaButton1}</button>)}
```

The idea is to send users from [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) to [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com). But what is the equivalent of Link to(React) in Preact?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use buttons for links, that comes with many accessibility issues.

This also isn't relevant to React or Preact, this is what plain HTML anchor tags do.

```html
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

If you really need to do this on button press (which I cannot recommend against doing enough), it entirely depends on what router you're using. React comes with no built-in way to redirect, and neither does Preact. You can be using dozens of different routers with Preact, so there's no way of answering this.